# Is it possible to access the JUnit @TempDir-path from production code?

Tags: java, spring, junit-jupiter

Consider a Spring (Boot) application that's generating files to an output folder whenever its service is invoked. I'm trying to test this kind of functionality with JUnit Jupiter, but I want the generated files to be discarded after my test, which is why I'm currently trying to use `@TempDir`. It seems to do exactly what I want, but I'm struggling to instruct my Spring context to send the generated files to the temporary directory.

**MyService.java**

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Value("${myservice.output-directory}")
    private String outputDirectory;

    public void generateOutputFiles() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**MyServiceTest.java**

```java
@SpringBootTest
class MyServiceTest {
    @TempDir
    protected static Path outputDirectory;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void test1() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My question is therefore, is there a clean way of setting the `myservice.output-directory` property to the absolute path of the temporary directory?

Comment: This test should be a unit test, not an integration test. And you should use constructor injection, not field injection. Once you have done that, all you need to do to test your service is to construct an instance using `new MyService(outputDirectory)`. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#unit-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ReflectionTestUtils` for these kinda situation. Either you can do in test method or in `@Before` in Unit test and this will override if you already configured any value from `application.yml` from resources directory.

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyServiceTest {
    @TempDir
    protected static Path outputDirectory;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void test1() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myService, "outputDirectory", outputDirectory);
    }
}
```